# dotnet core multiple auth schemes: authentication handler is not being triggered

Tags: authentication, .net-core

Dotnet Core 3.1. I have two custom authentication schemes and handlers. When controller action has an `[Authorize]` attribute then both handlers get triggered. When there is no `[Authorize]` attribute then only the default scheme gets triggered. I cannot put Authorize attribute on the controller action, but still need to get claims set by the second Auth scheme. How can I ensure that not only the default auth handler is triggered?

Here is my simplified setup.cs:

```
    services
        .AddAuthentication("Auth1")
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, Auth1>("Auth1", null)
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, Auth2>("Auth2", null);

    services
        .AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Auth1", "Auth2")
                .Build();
        });
```

Auth1 and Auth2 handlers are like this (also just for demo):

```
public class Auth1 : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{ 
    ....
    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());
    }
}

public class Auth2 : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{ 
    ....
    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and reproduced that in ASP.NET Core 3.1. I think that you forgot to register authentication middleware, so it's only triggering in the case of authorization.

My reproduced app behaved the same way as you described, but as soon I added the line from below into the startup.cs, breakpoints in the default authentication scheme Auth1 started being caught while debugging.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Remember, to place this before UseAuthorization and keep in mind that only Auth1 will be invoked since you set it as the default authentication scheme.